# Clearing entry box values in tkinter error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to get tkinter to clear an entry box each time a button is pressed

How I want my program to work is this. Whenever a user selects a statistical distribution, a row of varriable entry boxes appears to the right (the number of variable entry boxes vary by statisical distribution. I would like the user to be able to change the values of the entry boxes multiple times. The variables then feed into a calculation later in the script.

Currently, the entry box only stores and returns the first value entered by the user. Therefore, I want to clear the entrybox each time before the final calculation is called. I know that I need to use the variablename.delete(0,END) command, but I am having trouble with its implementation. I can succsefully get the entrybox to clear, but for some reason,  whenever I insert this syntax into the code, my labeling syntax ceases working.

Below is my current code. I have included 2 separate blocks of the code. The first shows my current attempt on fixing the problem using the variablename.delete(0,END) method. The deleting method works fine, but for some reason

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *
from scipy.stats import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


master = tk.Tk()
master.title("Gas Calculator")
v = tk.IntVar()
combo = Combobox(master)
#possible entry boxes depending on the statistic distribution chosen
f1 = tk.Entry(master)
f2 = tk.Entry(master)
f3 = tk.Entry(master)
f4 = tk.Entry(master)
f5 = tk.Entry(master)
f6 = tk.Entry(master)
f7 = tk.Entry(master)
f8 = tk.Entry(master)
f1.grid(row=3, column=5)
f2.grid(row=3, column=6)
f3.grid(row=3, column=7)
f4.grid(row=3, column=8)
f5.grid(row=3, column=9)
f6.grid(row=3, column=10)
#calls the users distribution selection and then is supposed to format the boxes accordinly
def callbackARS(eventObject):

    ARDist=(comboARS.get())

    try:
        if ARDist == "Truncated Normal":
            f1.delete(0,tk.END) 
            f1 = tk.Entry(master)
            f2 = tk.Entry(master)
            f3 = tk.Entry(master)
            f4 = tk.Entry(master)
            f5 = tk.Entry(master,state='disabled')
            f6 = tk.Entry(master,state='disabled')

            f1.grid(row=3, column=5)
            f2.grid(row=3, column=6)
            f3.grid(row=3, column=7)
            f4.grid(row=3, column=8)
            f5.grid(row=3, column=9)
            f6.grid(row=3, column=10)

            tk.Label(master, text="Mean Value", padx=20, width=10, bg = "light blue").grid(row=2,column=5)
            tk.Label(master, text="Standard Deviation", padx=20, width=10, bg = "light blue").grid(row=2,column=6)
            tk.Label(master, text="Low Limit", padx=20, width=10, bg = "light blue").grid(row=2,column=7)
            tk.Label(master, text="High Limit", padx=20, width=10, bg = "light blue").grid(row=2,column=8)
            tk.Label(master, text="", padx=20, width=10).grid(row=2,column=9)
            tk.Label(master, text="", padx=20, width=10).grid(row=2,column=10)


        return test
        return test2
    except:
        pass   

#function to allow users to select what distribution they want
comboARS = Combobox(master)
comboARS['values']= ("Truncated Normal", "Normal", "Discrete")
comboARS.current(0) #set the selected item
comboARS.grid(row=3, column=3)
comboARS.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", callbackARS)



#testing function to check and make sure the input boxes are being cleared. needs to be used in cuncjuntion with the button coded below.
def testing():

    test1 = float(f1.get())
    test2 = float(f2.get())
    testsum = test1 * test2
    print (testsum)
tk.Button(master, text='Calculate', command=testing, width=20).grid(row=35, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)
```

Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: You've posted way too much code. If your problem is with clearing an entry, your [mcve] only needs a single entry, plus enough code to show how you're trying to clear it.

Comment: @BryanOakley  thank you for the feedback. I have gone back and edited out as much as I can

Comment: So, you're claiming this problem only happens when you have 6 entry widgets and six labels?